# How to get the last 3 letters in a string?

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm trying to get the last three characters in a string. With the following code, I'm trying to get the last three characters of the `fname` variable, but I'm getting a "The method Length(int) is undefined for the type String" error:

```
 String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
 String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
 String number = request.getParameter("number");

 String firstPart = lname.substring(0, 3);
 String middlePart = fname.substring(0, fname.Length(3));
```

Comment: You already doing it. Did you test your code ?

Comment: Yes. But I'm getting this error: "The method Length(int) is undefined for the type String"

Comment: Here: `fname.Length(3)`. Remove the `3`, and the method is called `length`, not `Length`.

Answer (score 7):

So there are two problems here:

Firstly you're calling `fname.Length(3)`, which doesn't make sense as [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) doesn't have a `Length(int n)` method on it. What it does have is a [`substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) method and a [`length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) method, which you can use as follows:

```
String middlePart = fname.substring(fname.length() - 3);
```

As outlined in the linked JavaDocs, `String.substring()` *"Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string."*. So if we can provide it with the index (or position) within the String `fname` where we want to start copying from.

If I've got a String such as `"Chicken"`, and I want the last 3 characters, I'd call `"Chicken".substring(4)`, and the result would be `"ken"` (Strings are zero-indexed, so the character 'k' has index 4).

Instead of hard coding the index where I want to start the substring from, I use the `String.length()` method which tells me how long a `String` is, and subtract 3. In the above example, `"Chicken".length()` is 7, and so `"Chicken".length() - 3` is the index where you should start substring-ing if you want the last 3 characters.

Comment: thanks! This is the right answer that I am looking for. But what do you mean by -3?

Comment: @samantha.nicole I've updated my answer to provide a bit more explanation. What I've done is kind of equivalent to `fname.substring(fname.length() - 3, fname.length())`, if that makes things clearer.

Answer (score 6):

```
String lastThreeChars = string.substring(string.length() - 3);
```

Comment: Then an upvote/setting the answer as valid would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Good practice would be to select this as the answer to your question, since the solution worked for you. This way your question will not appear in the Unanswered list any more and you are giving the person who wrote the question his reward.

Comment: be more polite!!! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-in

Comment: @Emd4600... I just checked and what I need is the last three chars. not the first three chars.

Comment: @samantha.nicole check it again.... substring(int) `Returns a string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string.`

Comment: @Phantomazi you know about delay before accepting an answer?

Comment: @JordiCastilla you cannot upvote, but you can accept. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Jordi Castilla True, I forgot. I just was telling him, because he might not know, and I think that if someone helps you, you can appreciate it doing that. Obviously it's not obligatory and people would help him regardless, but it's appreciated.

Comment: have you checked my link? please read before posting... and you might listen to users with bit more rep than you about how SO works...

Comment: accepting this answer **won't be a good practice**.... oh my god!!! *but why???* **[according this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)** there are good practices, and code-only answers are not really appreciated if they are not [code-descriptive](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258676/3850595).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see the link. I understand.